# PHP code works accurately but validation message not showing up

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show a validation message after running a MySQL update query in a `for` loop. I wrote the source code below but the validation message is not showing up. I don't know what the matter is.

**Here is my PHP code**

```
<?php
    // Update All rows start
    for ($i=0; $i<$setTotalRows ; $i++) 
    {
        $GetChecked = isset($_POST['txtChecked'.$i]);   
        $GetTransCode = $_POST['txttransCode'.$i];
        $GetTransType = $_POST['txttransSetType'.$i];
        $GetTransMethod = $_POST['txtPaymentMethod'.$i];
        $SetEncodedDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if (empty($GetChecked)) { //Start Else
            continue;
        } else if (!empty($GetChecked) && $GetTransType == "ErrorType") {
            continue;
        } else {
            if($GetTransType == "Debit") { //Check For Cashin Cashout Start
                $SetTableName = "tblbank_cashin";
            } else {
                $SetTableName = "tblbank_cashout";
            } //Check For Cashin Cashout End

            //Method Start
            switch ($GetTransMethod) {
                case "1":
                    $SetPayMode = "Cash Deposit";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $SetPayMode = "Online Transfer";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    $SetPayMode = "Cheque Transfer";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    $SetPayMode = "Cash Withdrawal";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    $SetPayMode = "Cheque Withdrawal";
                    break;
                default:
                    $SetPayMode = "Cash Deposit";
            }
// Method End

            $sql_update = "UPDATE ". $SetTableName. " SET ";
            $sql_update .= "transRecon='1'";
            $sql_update .= ", transReconDate='$SetEncodedDate'";
            $sql_update .= ", transType='$SetPayMode'";
            $sql_update .= " WHERE transCode='$GetTransCode'";
            $result_reconcile = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_update);
            if(!$result_reconcile){
                die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
            //echo $result_reconcile;
            }
        } //End Else

    } //End For i loop

    if(isset($result_reconcile)){
        $sucess = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i> Perfect!</strong> payment(s) has been reconciled</div>";
        header('Refresh: 3;url=banks?P=All&E='.$view_bankid);
    } else {
        $error_display = "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>ERROR!</strong> An error occured. Please Try Again Here</div>";
    }
//Update All rows End
?>
```

Comment: That's not how you make a redirect with `header()`

Comment: And please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: Where is the validation message?

Comment: i know but my requirements is to redirect after 3 seconds

Comment: @RobertRocha please look for `if(isset($result_reconcile)){` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP headers must be sent before any output is displayed, you also are never displaying `$success`, as you only set the variable, never echoing it.

If you are able to use Javascript, then echo out your `$success` in the php itself, then I would suggest using jQuery for the following, echo'd out after the php `$success` message.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.replace("some webpage here");
  }, 3000);
});</script>
```

Comment: On main page i already displaying $success message and it works on other forms but in this code it wont showing up

Comment: It's not showing up because you never echo it, and if you did, then your header() would not work...

Comment: OK I commented header() statement but still not showing up

Comment: @Rtra because you never `echo $sucess; `

Comment: you were right bro, I fixed the `$sucess` was set to null I removed that statement and it works